# Case statement in SELECT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a query as following:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2  
      ON Table2.field1 LIKE CASE WHEN Table2.field2= 1 
                                 THEN  Table1.field1 
                                 WHEN Table2.field2 = 2 
                                 THEN Table1.field1 + '%' 
                            END
```

The query is taking too much execution time.While checking the plan I found the time is spending due to matching. How can I re-write the  CASE statement in the SELECT to minimize execution time?

Comment: Your joining using a LIKE operator which will perform a tablescan everytime. I don't see a way to improve execution time if your joining condition is so variable.

Comment: +1 @Matt. You are probably better off splitting the code into branching logic if the performance is bad enough. Just be careful of plan caching if this code lives in a proc...you might need to nest some procs with the separated logic to ensure proper plan caching/performance.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with this join:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2  
  ON
    (Table2.field2=1 AND Table2.field1=Table1.field1)
    OR
    (Table2.field2=2 AND Table2.field1 LIKE Table1.field1 + '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be like? can you use equals instead. The thinking is in that case you can just use substring or something as part of the second case to create a psudo version of your current check. It would look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2  
  ON Case WHEN Table2.field2= 1 
          Then Table2.field1 = Table1.field1
          When Table2.field2 = 2
          Then Substring(Table2.field1, 1, Len(Table1.field1)) = Table1.Field1
     END
```

A little iffy on if this will work as is though, mainly because of the lack of an else case.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the query below:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
  LEFT JOIN Table2  
    ON Table2.field1 = Table1.field1
WHERE Table2.field2 = 1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
  LEFT JOIN Table2  
    ON Table2.field1 LIKE Table1.field1 + '%'
WHERE Table2.field2= 2
```

Make sure field1 is indexed. If field2 only has 2 possible values there is no use indexing it.